# move AD group by file

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm new with PS and doing my first steps..
I have a file named `"C:\temp\used_groups.csv"`.
The file has email address of AD Groups populated by Powershell script to check which distributions group are being used in 365.
Now I want to be able to move them to different OU.

the file has some AD group's email address as follow:

```
"RecipientAddress"
"test@test.com"
"test1@test.com"
"test2@test.com"
```

1. is it possible to move the AD group only by their email address attribute?
2. how can I resolve the group's `sAMAccountName` attribute by their  email address attribute?

this is what I tried with no success:

```
 $Groups=import-csv "C:\temp\used_groups.csv"
 ForEach ($Group in $Groups){ 
    Get-ADGroup -Filter "mail -like $Group "
    # rest of script.. not done yet. 
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
# put the DistinghuishedName of the destination OU here
$destinationOU = "OU=Test,DC=Fabrikam,DC=COM"

# read the CSV and grab the 'RecipientAddress' fields in an array
$emailAddresses = (Import-Csv "C:\temp\used_groups.csv").RecipientAddress
foreach ($email in $emailAddresses){ 
    $GroupToMove = Get-ADGroup -Filter "mail -like '$email'"
    if ($GroupToMove) {
        # Move-ADObject takes the 'DistinghuishedName' or the 'objectGUID' as Identity parameter
        # but it also works when piping the group object itself to it.
        $GroupToMove | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $destinationOU
        Write-Host "Moved group '$($GroupToMove.Name)'."
    } 
    else {
        Write-Warning "Could not find group with email address '$email'"
    }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic as well !

Answer (score 2):

When using a CSV you have to specify the fieldname. Another problem in your script is the absence of quotes in the AD filter.

Try this:

```
$Groups=import-csv "C:\temp\used_groups.csv"
ForEach ($Group in $Groups){ 
    (Get-ADGroup -Filter "mail -like '$($Group.RecipientAddress)'").samaccountname
    # rest of script.. not done yet. 
}
```

Cheers,

Gert Jan